# How start my CKEditor instance with a specific HTML template instead of the default one?

Tags: html, templates, tags, ckeditor

I'm pretty new to CKEditor and I would use it this way.
I make CKEditor avalaible for users to create their own page and save it to the DB. It works like a charm, but I would have something more.

1. On every new instance, load a different HTML template instead of the defaut one (    )

Where Can i change this default template?

2. Also, I would put inside my template a single div (with a specific id) who the user CANNOT change at all.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `textarea` element for your editor, you can simply include your template in that textarea, like this:

```
<textarea id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my template
</textarea>
```

If you need to get the template HTML dynamically (for example from a database) you can do this when the page loads:

```
var template = getMyTemplateHtmlFromDB(); // You need to implement this of course
document.getElementById("editor1").value = template;
```

As for an untouchable `div` element, you could catch keystrokes while editing and prevent attempts to change this element or even create a [CKEditor widget](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) to allow only specific content within a set of "locked" elements, but it seems like a lot of work if all you want is to wrap the user generated content with a `div`. You can simply add that `div` later when saving the dynamic content or when displaying it somewhere.